# ActionView::Template::Error (couldn't find file )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I've updated my app to `rails 5.1` and spree to `spree 3.5` this caused several problems with the latest being.

```
  ActionView::Template::Error (couldn't find file 'jquery.validate/jquery.validate.min' with type 'application/javascript'
```

I've tried installing the gems like `gem 'jquery-rails'` `gem 'rails-ujs,'~> 0.1.0'` `gem "jquery-ui-rails"` `gem 'jquery-validation-rails'` and even added the files to my JavaScript folder.

Still no succes.

Anyone know the cause of the problem and how to solve it?

**gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
# gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'pg', '< 1'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'truncate_html', '~> 0.9.3'
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'rails-ujs', '~> 0.1.0'
gem "jquery-ui-rails"
gem 'jquery-validation-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', group: :doc

gem 'rake'
gem 'rspec'
gem 'kramdown'
gem 'thor', '0.19.1'
gem 'spree_braintree_vzero', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_braintree_vzero'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development


group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'capistrano-passenger'
  gem 'capistrano-rails'
  gem 'capistrano-rvm'

end

group :development do

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

gem 'spree', '~> 3.5.0.rc2'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', '~> 3.3'
gem 'spree_gateway', '~> 3.3'
gem 'devise'
gem 'materialize-sass'
gem 'active_link_to'
#gem 'mollie-api-ruby', '< 3.2'
# gem 'spree_mollie', github: 'salman15/mollie_spree_2017', branch: 'stable'
#gem 'spree_mollie', github: 'ttcremers/spree_mollie', branch: 'stable'
gem 'spree_mail_settings', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_mail_settings'
# gem 'spree_i18n', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_i18n'
# gem 'spree_globalize', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_globalize', branch: 'master'
gem "mini_magick"
gem 'spree_mollie_gateway'
# gem 'rails-i18n', github: 'svenfuchs/rails-i18n', branch: 'rails-4-x' # For 4.x
# gem 'globalize', '~> 5.1.0'
```

**all.js/application.js**

```
    // This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into including all the files listed below.
// Add new JavaScript/Coffee code in separate files in this directory and they'll automatically
// be included in the compiled file accessible from http://example.com/assets/application.js
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.validate
//= require spree/frontend

//= require_tree .
//= require spree/frontend/spree_auth
//= require spree/frontend/spree_braintree_vzero
```

Comment: show your `application.js` file

Comment: @RaviMariya Added

Comment: `couldn't find file 'jquery.validate/jquery.validate.min' with type 'application/javascript'` are you loading any js file from view?

Comment: @RaviMariya If you're meaning i'm running some scripts exclusively on some pages with 'view' you're right

Comment: maybe you're calling jquery.validate.min file from view? why you need it if you have it in your application.js?

Comment: I'm not loading in `jquery.validate.min` from view. I added it in after I got the error message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172759/discussion-between-salman-and-ravi-mariya).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixed the problem for me: I just removed the line

```
//= require jquery.validate/jquery.validate.min
```

from frontend.js